# Finding two values existing in same object array using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array with flight detail like from, to and cost of the tickets. I'm trying to show the flight details for particular from-to.
For example: if the user selects from as bangaluru and to as delhi then I should show the corresponding detail.I used set to have the print the unique values.Is there any way to check if from and to belongs to same object then it should show details of the object.

I tried the below, but it just checks the overall array.

```
 if((flightDetails.includes(orginVal)) && (flightDetails.includes(destinationVal))){
            alert("hello");
         }
```

Js code:

```
       flightDetails=[{
       "airline": "B-201",
       "from": "Bangaluru(BLR)",
       "to": "Delhi(DEL)",
       "detail": [{
         "date": "2019-12-30",
         "price": "3900",
         "departTime": "12:00 PM",
         "arriveTime": "14:00 PM",
         "seats":"10"
       }, {
         "date": "2019-12-31",
         "price": "3000",
         "departTime": "17:30 PM",
         "arriveTime": "19:30 PM",
         "seats":"3"
       }, {
         "date": "2019-06-01",
         "price": "2100",
         "departTime": "09:00 AM",
         "arriveTime": "11:00 AM",
         "seats":"7"
       }]
     },{
       "airline": "B-202",
       "from": "Delhi(DEL)",
       "to": "Bangaluru(BLR)",
       "detail": [{
         "date": "2019-12-30",
         "price": "3000",
         "departTime": "12:00 PM",
         "arriveTime": "14:00 PM",
         "seats":"10"
       }, {
         "date": "2019-12-31",
         "price": "3000",
         "departTime": "17:30 PM",
         "arriveTime": "19:30 PM",
         "seats":"3"
       }, {
         "date": "2019-06-01",
         "price": "2100",
         "departTime": "09:00 AM",
         "arriveTime": "11:00 AM",
         "seats":"7"
       }]
     }]

inputOrigin=document.getElementById('origin');
inputDesination=  document.getElementById("desination");
originOptions=document.getElementById('originCountry');
destinationOptions= document.getElementById('desinationCountry');

var originCategories = new Set();
var destinationCategories = new Set();

flightDetails.forEach((o) => originCategories.add(o.from));
originCategories = [...originCategories];

flightDetails.forEach((o) => destinationCategories.add(o.to));
destinationCategories = [...destinationCategories];


for(i=0;i<originCategories.length;i++) {
   originOptions.innerHTML+=' <option>'+originCategories[i]+'<option>';
}

for(i=0;i<destinationCategories.length;i++) {
   destinationOptions.innerHTML+=' <option>'+destinationCategories[i]+'<option>';
}
```

Comment: honestly speaking I cannot make out what you are trying to do and what exactly is the problem

Comment: Okay, there will be from and to while you are booking a flight.I have a json which will have from and to in the same object.I need to check whether the from and to is from the same object in order to its corresponding details.Am I clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `filter`, which will return an array with matches. If you only expect one, you can of course pop that element out of it:

```js
var flightDetails=[{"airline": "B-201","from": "Bangaluru(BLR)","to": "Delhi(DEL)","detail": [{"date": "2019-12-30","price": "3900","departTime": "12:00 PM","arriveTime": "14:00 PM","seats":"10"}, {"date": "2019-12-31","price": "3000","departTime": "17:30 PM","arriveTime": "19:30 PM","seats":"3"}, {"date": "2019-06-01","price": "2100","departTime": "09:00 AM","arriveTime": "11:00 AM","seats":"7"}]},{"airline": "B-202","from": "Delhi(DEL)","to": "Bangaluru(BLR)","detail": [{"date": "2019-12-30","price": "3000","departTime": "12:00 PM","arriveTime": "14:00 PM","seats":"10"}, {"date": "2019-12-31","price": "3000","departTime": "17:30 PM","arriveTime": "19:30 PM","seats":"3"}, {"date": "2019-06-01","price": "2100","departTime": "09:00 AM","arriveTime": "11:00 AM","seats":"7"}]}];
     
var originVal = "Delhi(DEL)";
var destinationVal = "Bangaluru(BLR)"
var matches = flightDetails.filter(detail => detail.from === originVal && detail.to === destinationVal);
console.log(matches);
```

As your existing code already collects the exact origins and destinations, from which the user makes a selection, I don't think it is useful to use `includes`. It will be more appropriate to look for exact matches.

`filter` will possibly return multiple results, so you should probably give the user a further selection possibility from that result list.

Answer (score 1):

You're comparing a js object rather than the `from-to` strings.

Use the function `find` and check for each object the attributes `from-to`.  This approach finds the first match and not the remaining matches, in that case, you can use the function `filter` instead.

*I'm assuming the final user will write a string like `originVal="Bangal"` and `destinationVal="Del"`*

```js
let flightDetails = [{  "airline": "B-201",  "from": "Bangaluru(BLR)",  "to": "Delhi(DEL)",  "detail": [{    "date": "2019-12-30",    "price": "3900",    "departTime": "12:00 PM",    "arriveTime": "14:00 PM",    "seats": "10"  }, {    "date": "2019-12-31",    "price": "3000",    "departTime": "17:30 PM",    "arriveTime": "19:30 PM",    "seats": "3"  }, {    "date": "2019-06-01",    "price": "2100",    "departTime": "09:00 AM",    "arriveTime": "11:00 AM",    "seats": "7"  }]}, {  "airline": "B-202",  "from": "Delhi(DEL)",  "to": "Bangaluru(BLR)",  "detail": [{    "date": "2019-12-30",    "price": "3000",    "departTime": "12:00 PM",    "arriveTime": "14:00 PM",    "seats": "10"  }, {    "date": "2019-12-31",    "price": "3000",    "departTime": "17:30 PM",    "arriveTime": "19:30 PM",    "seats": "3"  }, {    "date": "2019-06-01",    "price": "2100",    "departTime": "09:00 AM",    "arriveTime": "11:00 AM",    "seats": "7"  }]}],
    originVal = "Bangaluru",
    destinationVal = "Delhi",
    found = flightDetails.find(({from, to}) => from.includes(originVal) && to.includes(destinationVal));

if (found) console.log(found.detail);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Great,It worked.But on click a from or to which is not in the particular ob, it shows either orginVal reference error or destinationVal reference error.

Comment: @HemaNandagopal I didn't get it, can you show the complete code?

Comment: It shows as "TypeError: Cannot read property 'detail' of undefined" in try and catch if I give a value for from and to whcih is not in the same object..

Comment: @HemaNandagopal because of that, the code snippet has a `if (found)`

Comment: @trincot there is a property called `detail` for each object.

Answer (score 0):

You can take input and than find the object based on from and to property

```js
let flightDetails = [{"airline":"B-201","from":"Bangaluru(BLR)","to":"Delhi(DEL)","detail":[{"date":"2019-12-30","price":"3900","departTime":"12:00PM","arriveTime":"14:00PM","seats":"10"},{"date":"2019-12-31","price":"3000","departTime":"17:30PM","arriveTime":"19:30PM","seats":"3"},{"date":"2019-06-01","price":"2100","departTime":"09:00AM","arriveTime":"11:00AM","seats":"7"}]},{"airline":"B-202","from":"Delhi(DEL)","to":"Bangaluru(BLR)","detail":[{"date":"2019-12-30","price":"3000","departTime":"12:00PM","arriveTime":"14:00PM","seats":"10"},{"date":"2019-12-31","price":"3000","departTime":"17:30PM","arriveTime":"19:30PM","seats":"3"},{"date":"2019-06-01","price":"2100","departTime":"09:00AM","arriveTime":"11:00AM","seats":"7"}]}]

function values(){
  let fromIn = document.getElementById('from').value
  let toIn = document.getElementById('to').value
  let details = flightDetails.find(( {from,to} ) => from === fromIn && to === toIn)
  console.log(details)
}
```

```html
<input id='from' placeholder='From'></input>
<input id='to' placeHolder='To'></input>
<button onClick=values()>Give me details</button>
```